# How do I pull out sublists from a list under a given condition?

Tags: list-manipulation

is there an easy way to pull sublists out of a "master list" based upon certain conditions?

Let's say I have a list:

```
list1={{{1a,1b},{1a,1c},{1a,1a},{1y,1y}}}
```

and:

```
list2={{{15,15},{15,2},{15,15},{10,10}}
```

The two lists show two representations of the same thing, i.e. "list2" the elements of `1a = 15, 1b = 15, 1c = 2, 1y= 10`.  What I'm trying to do is two-fold, first I want to make a list of subsets (derived from list1) which contain 1a in them (the 1a can be in any position).  So that would give us the list:

```
nlist1={{{1a,1b},{1a,1c},{1a,1a}}}
```

Then I want to take that nlist1 and compare it to list2 to create a new list. The new list is a sublist of nlist1 in which both values given by list2 are equal.  That would give the output of:

```
nlist2={{{1a,1b},{1a,1a}}}
```

I tried to tackle this with an `If` statement but I was having trouble getting the sublists to print the same way they're shown in the list themselves.

Comment: symbol names cannot start with numbers:`list1={{{1a,1b},{1a,1c},{1a,1a},{1y,1y}}}` does not work as you intend. You can use `list1 = {{{a1, b1}, {a1, c1}, {a1, a1}, {y1, y1}}};` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = {{{a1, b1}, {a1, c1}, {a1, a1}, {y1, y1}}};
list2 = {{{15, 15}, {15, 2}, {15, 15}, {10, 10}}};

assoc = AssociationThread[Flatten @ list1, Flatten @ list2]
```

> ```
>  <|a1 -> 15, b1 -> 15, c1 -> 2, y1 -> 10|>
> ```

```
nlist1 = Cases[list1, {a1, _} | {_, a1}, All]
```

> ```
> {{a1, b1}, {a1, c1}, {a1, a1}}
> ```

```
Select[Equal @@ # /. assoc &]@nlist1
```

> ```
>  {{a1, b1}, {a1, a1}}
> ```

Also

```
Pick[nlist1, Equal @@@ ( nlist1 /. assoc)]
Cases[{a_, b_} /; (Equal[a, b] /. assoc)] @ nlist1
DeleteCases[_?(DuplicateFreeQ[# /. assoc] &)] @ nlist1
```

all give

> ```
>  {{a1, b1}, {a1, a1}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
nlist2={Select[Extract[list1,Position[list2, {x_,x_}]], MemberQ[#,a1]&]}
```

> {{{a1, b1}, {a1, a1}}}

**Lists**

```
list1={{{a1,b1},{a1,c1},{a1,a1},{y1,y1}}};
list2={{{15,15},{15,2},{15,15},{10,10}}};
```